# What would be an example that submagma of a group which is not a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(G,*)$ be a group and $H$ be a submagma of $G$.

I'm sure that $H$ need not be a group, but what would be an example?

Answer (score 2):

Any such submagma would, in particular, be a [semigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup).

An example: out of the group $\Bbb Z$ (under addition), we can take the submagma $2 \Bbb Z_{>0} = \{2,4,6,\dots\}$.  Note that we have no identity element, and that no elements have inverses.